# Controller Action Method is not getting called when custom routebase class is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Following is the Custom RouteBase class

```
 public class CustomRoutingBehaviour:RouteBase
        {
            string[] allowedUrl;
            public CustomRoutingBehaviour(string[] url)
            {
                allowedUrl = url;
            }

            public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {
                RouteData route = null;
                string browsedurl = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
                if(allowedUrl.Contains(browsedurl,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    route = new RouteData(this,new MvcRouteHandler());
                    route.Values.Add("controller","CustomiziedController");
                    route.Values.Add("action","Index");
                    route.Values.Add("BrowsedURL",browsedurl);

                }

            return route;
            }

            public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Following is the routing configuration:

```
routes.Add(new CustomRoutingBehaviour(new string[] { "~/Customizied/Index", "~/Customizied/Index1" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I have resolved adding an ending slash (**/**) at url address in the browser. Pay attention to handle the slash in your code. You can add the final slash at every url of the array you pass in ctor of your **CustomRoutingBehaviour** class or substring **browsedurl** variable.
I don't know why this way it works.